# Secure communication between Flutter App and Web PHP

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm learning Flutter myself and need some expert guidance on the right way to do what I want.

I would like to allow the user of my Flutter application to securely send some sensitive data (e.g. email, phone number, name etc.) to my PHP based website (with REST API) and then, after some time, I would like to send a reply (e.g. . text) from my website to the sender's device and displaying it on the User's screen.

I suspect I should use Firebase Cloud Messaging for this - am I right?

I found tutorials that explain how to send data from Flutter-> FCM and from PHP(curl)-> FCM. But I can't find the tutorial explaining how to send data from Flutter-> FCM-> PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is typically used to send messages **from** the server **to** the application, when the user may not be actively using it. While it *can* be used to send messages from the client to a server, it is much less common for that.

That's because calling a PHP API from your Flutter app is no different than retrieving any data from the internet, and can be accomplished in a multitude of ways. One of the simpler approaches is documented in Flutter's [fetching data from the internet](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) page and uses the `http` package.

Comment: What about security? Will I have to send all sensitive data every time I call my API? I didn't mention it, but at the same time I would like to secure the server against fake calls.

Maybe I should use the Cloud function? A registered Firebase user will run a Cloud function that retrieves all sensitive data from the Firebase database and post it securely to my PHP API using an API key? And then I can use FCM to reply to the user from my PHP API?

Comment: It is *your* responsibility to secure the API. If you want to allow any user of your app to send any message they want to any other user of the app, then simply checking their authenticate state (either in Cloud Functions or by [verifying the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) yourself) may be good enough. You could also consider using App Check to verify that the calls come from your client-side application code, which requires a similar [token verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend) but now for an app token.

Comment: App Check looks promising, but I only see the option doing this using Node.js? Is it possible to check app token using PHP?